# Soundcloud: The requested URL responded with HTTP code 0

Tags: curl, soundcloud

I moved my code base from one server to another - no code change, the only difference being https. I modified my app in Soundcloud developers to be `https://url` , however I continuously receive this error:

```
[20-Sep-2013 15:08:35 Europe/London] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Services_Soundcloud_Invalid_Http_Response_Code_Exception' with message 'The requested URL responded with HTTP code 0.' in /system/soundcloud/Soundcloud.php:945
Stack trace:
#0 /soundcloud/Soundcloud.php(298): Soundcloud->_request('https://api.sou...', Array)
#1 /application/controllers/speaker/media.php(190): Soundcloud->credentialsFlow('soundcloud@...', '073ffbc3b66691c...')
#2 [internal function]: Media->add_audio()
#3 /system/core/CodeIgniter.php(359): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#4 /index.php(202): require_once('/home/iwantasp/...')
#5 {main}
  thrown in /system/soundcloud/Soundcloud.php on line 945
```

Again, this code worked perfectly on the previous server, it's merely server change.

We have implemented the security cert that is usually the cause for this problem to no avail ([Soundcloud (Oauth2) API getting access token fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5533084/soundcloud-oauth2-api-getting-access-token-fails)) - we're on a linux system anyways so shouldn't make a difference.

cURL also works on this server.

What else could cause my problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's hard to debug this exception without seeing the source code. But my guess is that your problem might be related to this issue:

https://github.com/mptre/php-soundcloud/issues/3

Which means that you should modify your `accessToken` call and include the extra cURL parameters.

```php
$accessToken = $soundcloud->accessToken($code, $postData, array(
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => false,
));
```

Comment: Thanks very much, that was the issue.

Comment: Thanks, this helped solve my problem, although I ended up using `$soundcloud->setCurlOptions()`. If you do this it works for all your API calls, instead of just for `accessToken`.

Answer (score 3):

A much better solution would be to follow the answer listed on the following answer to [Twitter API returns NULL on XAMPP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18590990/50913) which states that you should update the CA root certifications for your PHP solution.

For more information:

- http://www.saotn.org/stop-turning-off-curlopt_ssl_verifypeer-and-fix-your-php-config/
- http://snippets.webaware.com.au/howto/stop-turning-off-curlopt_ssl_verifypeer-and-fix-your-php-config/