# Soundcloud PHP HTTP Code 0 [code worked for months unchanged]

Tags: php, soundcloud

I've found some posts about HTTP code 0, but they don't quite seem related to my context. My PHP code has been working unchanged for months, and it's suddenly generating HTTP code 0 errors.

```
$client = new Services_Soundcloud($client_Id, $client_secret, $callback_url);

//The requested URL responded with HTTP code 0. error raised here:
$temptrack = json_decode($client->get('tracks/'.trim($track_id)));
```

Comment: it would make sense to ask the API support

Comment: You saw that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18919021/soundcloud-the-requested-url-responded-with-http-code-0 ?

Comment: I did see the question, but they had a move from one server to another and some change with HTTPS. I did not have any changes on my side. API Support on Souncloud says it's moved over here. Hopefully they are monitoring for questions, and it's not just a blackbox.

Comment: Thanks for all your help. I tried the curl thing, but that didn't work. I believe something happened with the PHP curl cert store on my web host, which I can't update myself. The app is working again with another web host.

Answer (score 2):

Had a similar problem

In the SoundCloud API file

in the function (last function in my file)

```
protected function _request($url, $curlOptions = array())
```

I added

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```

above

```
curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
```

Seems to get me pass the HTTP Code 0 that I started getting recently.