# Soundcloud php API The requested URL responded with HTTP code 0

Tags: php, http, soundcloud

I am getting the response below when trying to upload a file to soundcloud using the soundcloud php api.

> The requested URL responded with HTTP code 0.

When trying to upload a file through the api.

It will get my data fine but not upload here is my full codeignitor controller.

I have tried all the suggested option to add the CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false but this doesnt seem to work for me can someone confirm it is working so i can narrow it down to my server.

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

/*
 * Soundcloud Controller
 */

class Soundcloud extends CI_Controller {


    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        require APPPATH.'/libraries/php-soundcloud-master/Services/Soundcloud.php';
        $this->soundcloud = new Services_Soundcloud('api key', 'api key', 'redirect uri');

    }

    function index(){
        $authorizeUrl = $this->soundcloud->getAuthorizeUrl();
        // Redirect to authorize url
        echo '<a href="' . $authorizeUrl . '">Connect with SoundCloud</a>';
    }

    function getme(){

        $url = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/' . APPPATH . 'libraries/php-soundcloud-master/test/test.mp3';
        try {
            $accessToken = $this->soundcloud->accessToken($_GET['code']);
        } catch (Services_Soundcloud_Invalid_Http_Response_Code_Exception $e) {
            exit($e->getMessage());
        }

        /*
        $this->soundcloud->setCurlOptions(array(
            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 0,
            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 0
        ));
        */
        try {
            $me = json_decode($this->soundcloud->get('me'), true);
        } catch (Services_Soundcloud_Invalid_Http_Response_Code_Exception $e) {
            exit($e->getMessage());
        }

// this will print out all my data fine
        echo "<pre>";
            print_r($me);
        echo "</pre>";
        $track_data = array(
            //'track[sharing]' => 'private',
            'track[title]' => 'Testing API',
            //'track[tags]' => null,
            'track[asset_data]' => '@' . $url
        );
        // perform the actual upload to soundcloud.
        try {
            $response = json_decode(
                $this->soundcloud->post('tracks', $track_data),
                true
            );
        } catch (Services_Soundcloud_Invalid_Http_Response_Code_Exception $e) {
            show_error($e->getMessage());
        }

    }   
}
```

Comment: Status seems ok [here](http://status.soundcloud.com/). Perhaps [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18919021/soundcloud-the-requested-url-responded-with-http-code-0) is related? I don't know much about their API, unfortunately.